# Wrapping things in css/flex

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have 4 items that need to be wrapped in css using flex. 3 items in a row and then a single item.

```
.movies {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items:flex-start;
    flex: 1 0 33%;
}
```

I cant (not allowed) use direction column.

no matter what I do this always ends up in one row where I need to scroll sideways.

Comment: `flex-wrap: wrap` - by default the wrap property is `nowrap`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `width: calc(100% / 3);` on the `flex` children, then specify `flex-wrap: wrap;` on your `flex` parent.

```css
.movies {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items:flex-start;
    flex: 1 0 33%;
}

.movies > div {
  width: calc(100%/3);
}
```

```html
<div class="movies">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This one did work. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to scroll sideways is {flex-wrap: wrap;}

```css
.movies {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items:flex-start;
  flex: 1 0 33%;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```